# Conformal Map from Intersection of Two Discs and Half-Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I have one of those "find the map" problems that is really giving me a lot of trouble.  Let $B_1(1)$ be the ball of radius $1$ centered at $1$.  We have the following domain: $\mathbb{D} \cap B_1(1) \cap \mathbb{H}$, the intersection of two discs with the upper half-plane, and we want a conformal isomorphism to $\mathbb{D}$ (or $\mathbb{H}$ of course).  For convenience, the two circles intersect in $\mathbb{H}$ at $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$.

I know how to do this for the intersection of two discs, but not these three regions (three discs, really).  I feel like the way to proceed is either to find a map sending this region to a half-strip (which is also the intersection of three "discs"), or use some LFT sending the three "corners" to judiciously chosen points, but I can't figure it out at all.  If we can map it to a slitted plane, or plane missing a bounded interval, or a half-strip, or a sector, then I can proceed from there, but otherwise I am totally stumped.

Alternatively, does anyone know if the function used for the intersection of just the two discs behaves well on the "top half" of this region?  For all I know it maps it to a quadrant or something.  EDIT: This approach doesn't seem fruitful after looking into it a bit more.

Anyone see a way to proceed?  You would be saving my bacon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\dfrac12+\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}\,i$. Then $\dfrac{z-a}{z-\bar a}$ transforms the intersection of the two discs into an angle. The image of the segment $[0,1]$ is an arc of circumference perpendicular to the sides of the angle. Thus, the image of the intersection of the disks with the upper half-plane is either a circular sector or the outside of the sector. Can you continuue from here?

Comment: I don't immediately see that the image of [0, 1] is an arc "closing off" the sector, but if I figure that part out then I think I can finish it, yeah!  Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Since the real line does not pass through $a$ or $\bar a$, its image is a circle. Moreover, the real line is orthogonal to the boundaries of the discs, so the circle must be orthogonal to the sides of the angle (because the transformation preserves angles.)